# How to exit from main thread

Tags: go

```
func GoCountColumns(in chan []string, r chan Result, quit chan int) {
    for {
        select {
        case data := <-in:
            r <- countColumns(data) // some calculation function
        case <-quit:
            return // stop goroutine
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Welcome to the csv Calculator")
    file_path := os.Args[1]
    fd, _ := os.Open(file_path)
    reader := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(fd))
    var totalColumnsCount int64 = 0
    var totallettersCount int64 = 0
    linesCount := 0
    numWorkers := 10000
    rc := make(chan Result, numWorkers)
    in := make(chan []string, numWorkers)
    quit := make(chan int)
    t1 := time.Now()

    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        go GoCountColumns(in, rc, quit)
    }
    //start worksers
    go func() {
        for {
            record, err := reader.Read()
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }

            if linesCount%1000000 == 0 {
                fmt.Println("Adding to the channel")
            }
            in <- record
            //data := countColumns(record)
            linesCount++
            //totalColumnsCount = totalColumnsCount + data.ColumnCount
            //totallettersCount = totallettersCount + data.LettersCount
        }
        close(in)
    }()

    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        quit <- 1 // quit goroutines from main
    }
    close(rc)
    for i := 0; i < linesCount; i++ {
        data := <-rc
        totalColumnsCount = totalColumnsCount + data.ColumnCount
        totallettersCount = totallettersCount + data.LettersCount
    }

    fmt.Printf("I counted %d lines\n", linesCount)
    fmt.Printf("I counted %d columns\n", totalColumnsCount)
    fmt.Printf("I counted %d letters\n", totallettersCount)
    elapsed := time.Now().Sub(t1)
    fmt.Printf("It took %f seconds\n", elapsed.Seconds())
}
```

My Hello World is a program that reads a csv file and passes it to a channel. Then the goroutines should consume from this channel. 
My Problem is I have no idea how to detect from the main thread that all data was processed and I can exit my program.

Comment: A note on terminology: You have absolutely no control over threads in Go. You are only given control of goroutines.

Answer (score 2):

on top of other answers.

- Take (great) care that closing a channel should happen on the write call site, not the read call site. In `GoCountColumns` the `r` channel being written, the responsibility to close the channel are onto `GoCountColumns` function. Technical reasons are, it is the only actor knowing for sure that the channel will not being written anymore and thus is safe for close.

```golang
    func GoCountColumns(in chan []string, r chan Result, quit chan int) {
        defer close(r)     // this line.
        for {
            select {
            case data := <-in:
                r <- countColumns(data) // some calculation function
            case <-quit:
                return // stop goroutine
            }
        }
    }
```

- The function parameters naming convention, if i might say, is to have the destination as first parameter, the source as second, and others parameters along. The `GoCountColumns` is preferably written:

```golang
    func GoCountColumns(dst chan Result, src chan []string, quit chan int) {
        defer close(dst)
        for {
            select {
            case data := <-src:
                dst <- countColumns(data) // some calculation function
            case <-quit:
                return // stop goroutine
            }
        }
    }
```

- You are calling `quit` right after the process started. Its illogical. This `quit` command is a force exit sequence, it should be called once an exit signal is detected, to force exit the current processing in best state possible, possibly all broken. In other words, you should be relying on the `signal.Notify` package to capture exit events, and notify your workers to quit. see https://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/#example_Notify

To write better parallel code, list at first the routines you need to manage the program lifetime, identify those you need to block onto to ensure the program has finished before exiting.

In your code, exists `read`, `map`. To ensure complete processing, the program main function must ensure that it captures a signal when `map` exits before exiting itself. Notice that the `read` function does not matter.

Then, you will also need the code required to capture an exit event from user input.

Overall, it appears we need to block onto two events to manage lifetime. Schematically,

```golang
func main(){
    go read()
    go map(mapDone)
    go signal()
    select {
        case <-mapDone:
        case <-sig:
    }
}
```

This simple code is good to `process or die`. Indeed, when the user event is caught, the program exits immediately, without giving a chance to others routines to do something required upon stop.

To improve those behaviors, you need first a way to signal the program wants to leave to other routines, second, a way to wait for those routines to finish their stop sequence before leaving.

To signal exit event, or cancellation, you can make use of a `context.Context`, pass it around to the workers, make them listen to it.

Again, schematically,

```golang
func main(){
    ctx,cancel := context.WithCancel(context.WithBackground())
    go read(ctx)
    go map(ctx,mapDone)
    go signal()
    select {
        case <-mapDone:
        case <-sig:
            cancel()
    }
}
```

(more onto read and map later)

To wait for completion, many things are possible, for as long as they are thread safe. Usually, a `sync.WaitGroup` is being used. Or, in cases like yours where there is only one routine to wait for, we can re use the current `mapDone` channel.

```golang
func main(){
    ctx,cancel := context.WithCancel(context.WithBackground())
    go read(ctx)
    go map(ctx,mapDone)
    go signal()
    select {
        case <-mapDone:
        case <-sig:
            cancel()
            <-mapDone
    }
}
```

That is simple and straight forward. But it is not totally correct. The last mapDone chan might block forever and make the program unstoppable. So you might implement a second signal handler, or a timeout.

Schematically, the timeout solution is

```golang
func main(){
    ctx,cancel := context.WithCancel(context.WithBackground())
    go read(ctx)
    go map(ctx,mapDone)
    go signal()
    select {
        case <-mapDone:
        case <-sig:
            cancel()
            select {
                case <-mapDone:
                case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
    }
}
```

You might also accumulate a signal handling and a timeout in the last select.

Finally, there are few things to tell about `read` and `map` context listening.

Starting with `map`, the implementation requires to read for `context.Done` channel regularly to detect `cancellation`.

It is the easy part, it requires to only update the select statement.

```golang
    func GoCountColumns(ctx context.Context, dst chan Result, src chan []string) {
        defer close(dst)
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                <-time.After(time.Minute) // do something more useful.
                return // quit. Notice the defer will be called.
            case data := <-src:
                dst <- countColumns(data) // some calculation function
            }
        }
    }
```

Now the `read` part is bit more tricky as it is an IO it does not provide a `select`able programming interface and listening to the context channel cancellation might seem contradictory. It is. As IOs are blocking, impossible to listen the context. And while reading from the context channel, impossible to read the IO. In your case, the solution requires to understand that your read loop is not relevant to your program lifetime (recall we only listen onto mapDone?), and that we can just ignore the context.

In other cases, if for example you wanted to restart at last byte read (so at every read, we increment an n, counting bytes, and we want to save that value upon stop). Then, a new routine is required to be started, and thus, multiple routines are to wait for completion. In such cases a `sync.WaitGroup` will be more appropriate.

Schematically,

```golang
func main(){
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    processDone:=make(chan struct{})
    ctx,cancel := context.WithCancel(context.WithBackground())
    go read(ctx)
    wg.Add(1)
    go saveN(ctx,&wg)
    wg.Add(1)
    go map(ctx,&wg)
    go signal()
    go func(){
        wg.Wait()
        close(processDone)
    }()
    select {
        case <-processDone:
        case <-sig:
            cancel()
            select {
                case <-processDone:
                case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
    }
}
```

In this last code, the waitgroup is being passed around. Routines are responsible to call for `wg.Done()`, when all routines are done, the `processDone` channel is closed, to signal the select.

```golang
    func GoCountColumns(ctx context.Context, dst chan Result, src chan []string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer close(dst)
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                <-time.After(time.Minute) // do something more useful.
                return // quit. Notice the defer will be called.
            case data := <-src:
                dst <- countColumns(data) // some calculation function
            }
        }
    }
```

It is undecided which patterns is preferred, but you might also see `waitgroup` being managed at call sites only.

```golang
func main(){
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    processDone:=make(chan struct{})
    ctx,cancel := context.WithCancel(context.WithBackground())
    go read(ctx)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(){
        defer wg.Done()
        saveN(ctx)
    }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(){
        defer wg.Done()
        map(ctx)
    }()
    go signal()
    go func(){
        wg.Wait()
        close(processDone)
    }()
    select {
        case <-processDone:
        case <-sig:
            cancel()
            select {
                case <-processDone:
                case <-time.After(time.Second):
            }
    }
}
```

Beyond all of that and OP questions, you must always evaluate upfront the pertinence of parallel processing for a given task. There is no unique recipe, practice and measure your code performances. see pprof.

Comment: wow, Thanks for the detailed explanation. At the end I'm still ending up managing signals and basically gorotines which is not better then other programing language...
One question: If I call defer close(r) It will close multiple times the receiving channel,

Comment: if you use the `v, ok := <-chan` syntax you will see it switches once from true to false, meaning chan was closed. not sure what you are referring to. Otherwise, yes this is all "low level" stuff and pretty verbose, it is the essence of golang to make programming as clearer as possible by avoiding hiding things. Now, nothing prevent you from building up an api to handle all this. something like [this](https://github.com/clementauger/orc) might help

Comment: I mean, ideally I would close the channel that sends that’s it.

Comment: that is not sufficient to handle the on going works. That only signals the end of input to the consumers of the channel. It is required to add an additional synchronization mechanism to ensure that the work being in process has a chance to finish, either into the actual expected result, or in the form of a temporary state for future restart. hth.

Answer (score 0):

There is way too much going on in this code. You should restructure your code into short functions that serve specific purposes to make it possible for someone to help you out easily (and help yourself as well).

You should read the following Go article, which goes into concurrency patterns:
https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

There are multiple ways to make one go-routine wait on some other work to finish. The most common ways are with wait groups (example I have provided) or channels.

```golang
func processSomething(...) {
    ...
}

func main() {
    workers := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        workers.Add(1) // you want to call this from the calling go-routine and before spawning the worker go-routine

        go func() {
            defer workers.Done() // you want to call this from the worker go-routine when the work is done (NOTE the defer, which ensures it is called no matter what)
            processSomething(....) // your async processing
        }()
    }

    // this will block until all workers have finished their work
    workers.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a channel to block `main` until completion of a goroutine.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        log.Println("bye")
        close(c)
    }()

    // This blocks until the channel is closed by the routine
    <-c
}
```

No need to write anything into the channel. Reading is blocked until data is read or, which we use here, the channel is closed.